# unable to select "fullwidth" on the POST (not page)

Tags: posts

On my WordPress  dashboard, when selecting `Posts> Add New` post,  there is no  `Page Attributes> Template` (Default template, fullwidth page, and so on) in the far right column. Because  the `Template` drop down menu is missing,  I am unable to select `fullwidth` on the **post**(not page), causing a sidebar to appear on the the screen displaying the post.

What to do to prevent the sidebar from appearing on the `post` display? I find template drop down menu  when adding a page, but not when adding a post. How can I select a `fullwidth` page on a Post if I don't have the options available to select it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no **`Page attributes`** because it's not a page and by default WordPress doesn't have an attribute to select template for post.

The page templates are coded in the theme that you are using.It seems that the theme has a template called `Full Width` defined as page template so you are able to select it for pages.

To not display the **`sidebar`** in the single blog post view you need to find out how it is being rendered either via `single.php` or `index.php` or by any other means.

If **`single.php`** is available in the theme and you find something like **`dynamic_sidebar('somename')`** then that's responsible for displaying the sidebar. If **`get_sidebar()`**  is available in **`single.php`** then look in the **`sidebar.php`**.To remove the sidebar you need to remove the corresponding sidebar and html structure also to make it full width.

The above explanation is for general cases and it differs depending on the theme.

**Refer:**

[Custom post](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for your message. Theme: Church WordPress theme is a Responsive HTML5 Omega child theme for WordPress. Any wordpress plugin to fix this problem instead of messing up with .php file. I'm new to php.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-a-post-without-a-sidebar

Comment: Now I resolved this problem using a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: Great! You have that solved